# Confluence - is there a way to link to the latest blog post in a space?

Tags: confluence

My specific use case is I'd like to put a link in the announcement banner in JIRA which says "Latest Blog Post in Dev Space" and that takes users to the most recent blog post in that space.

I'd prefer to not have to edit the announcement banner every time I add a blog post.

So instead of http://confluence.local/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1234 I would have http://confluence.local/display/DEVTEAM/latestblog/

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't pointing to the main blog page automatically show the latest blog post on top?

In that case your Jira just needs to link to the main blog page